# MySQL select all column names where condition is met for specific row

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause, unpivot

I have a table which links users to groups which is set up as below:
[image]

I would like to know if there is a method to select all groupIDs (column names) where a certain condition is met.

E.g. if I want to find all groups where user 2 has a level greater than 0 it would return (1,2,4)

It is also worth noting it cannot be done manually as there is roughly 5000 rows and 120 columns

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Does the column value have any other meaning other than the user is a member of a group - for example what does 3 mean in user id = 2 column 2

Comment: use Case When statements for each of your condition

Comment: With respect, this is the wrong way to do what you're trying to do. SQL is built to handle your kind of problem with association  tables with one row for each group/user combination. With proper indexes it can handle association tables without breaking a sweat even if they contain megarows. Your design, on the other hand, will require nightmarish queries as you're learning. And what if you need to add a new group a day for hundreds of days?

Comment: P.Salmon the different numbers represent different roles which will determine privileges etc

Comment: O.Jones thank you for the advice I think that's how I'll do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can unpivot and search with `union all`. Assuming that the columns of your table are called `grp1` to `grp5`:

```
select 1 as grp from t where userid = 2 and grp1 > 0
union all select 2 from t where userid = 2 and grp2 > 0
union all select 3 from t where userid = 2 and grp3 > 0
union all select 4 from t where userid = 2 and grp4 > 0
union all select 5 from t where userid = 2 and grp5 > 0
```

You should consider fixing your data model. Each user/group tuple should be stored in a separate row in a bridge table, like so:

`user_groups`:

```
userid    grp      val
     1      1        3
     1      2        2
     1      3        2
     1      4        2
     1      5        0
     ...
```

Then, the query is as simple as:

```
select grp from user_groups where userid = 2 and val > 0
```

Comment: I'm not commited to any table structure yet. I was just hoping to avoid one separate row for each user/group combination because the table would be huge (at least 500,000 rows) but if that's the best way to do it then I can do it that way 

Comment: My thoughts were that this is how MySQL handles their user privileges but I guess they don't need to run queries in both directions

Answer (score 0):

something like this

```
select distinct group from (
  select group1 group from t where level > 0
  union
  select group2 from t where level > 0
  union 
  select group3 from t where level > 0
  union
  select group4 from t where level > 0
  union
  select group5 from t where level > 0
)
```

Comment: The problem with this is that there will be at least 100 groups and it will always be increasing so it won't be practical to do it in this way

Answer (score 0):

You can use `concat_ws()` with `case` expressions:

```
select concat_ws(',',
                 case when `1` > 0 then 1 end,
                 case when `2` > 0 then 2 end,
                 case when `3` > 0 then 3 end,
                 case when `4` > 0 then 4 end,
                 case when `5` > 0 then 5 end
                )
from t
where userid = 2;
```

Note that you have a problem with our data model.  If you stored this data properly, then the solution would be simpler.  The proper way to store this would be one row per "group" and "level" for each user.